Adapter does not render elements in recyclerview, without errors in logs
Adapter does not render elements in recyclerview, and there are no errors in logcat.
I changed the background of the recyclerview and I know that it is displayed, but the elements that I add to it do not appear.Adapters written in the same way work on a different activity.
mainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DomainAdapter.OnClickListener {
    lateinit var adapter: DomainAdapter
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.rvDomains.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener{
            adapter = DomainAdapter(this, mutableListOf(DomainCVE(binding.etSearch.text.toString())), true)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(domain: DomainCVE) {
        val intent = Intent(this, DomainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("domain", domain)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

adapter
class DomainAdapter(private val context: Context, private val domain: MutableList<DomainCVE>, private val load: Boolean): RecyclerView.Adapter<DomainAdapter.DomainViewHolder>() {

    class DomainViewHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item){
        val binding = DomainItemsBinding.bind(item)

        fun bind(domain: DomainCVE, listener: OnClickListener) = with(binding){
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onClick(domain)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DomainViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.domain_items, parent, false)
        return DomainViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return domain.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DomainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.tvDomainName.text = domain[position].address
        if (load){
            holder.binding.ivDone.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            holder.binding.ivLoad.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            holder.binding.ivDone.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.binding.ivLoad.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }

    interface OnClickListener {
        fun onClick(domain: DomainCVE)
    }
}



so 2 reasons possible:

you're creating your adapter in onClick of a button, which would mean your data is displayed after some button is clicked, consider doing something like:

adapter = DomainAdapter(this, mutableListOf(DomainCVE(binding.etSearch.text.toString())), true)
binding.rvDomains.adapter = adapter
binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener{
    adapter.updateData(mutableListOf(DomainCVE(binding.etSearch.text.toString())))
}


you're not assigning the adapter to the recycler view in the onClick

binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener{
    adapter = DomainAdapter(this, mutableListOf(DomainCVE(binding.etSearch.text.toString())), true)
    binding.rvDomains.adapter = adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}


Thank you, I really forgot to assign the adapter for recyclerview

you can accept the answer to close the question then
